# binding camera to my game person with acceleration, deceleration, ect in libgdx project

Tags: camera, libgdx

So, how can I do this?
For example, my person goes right and camera starting to move to persons coordinates with acceleration, when he stoppes - camera moves to persons coordinates with deceleration. Of cource, I can make it by myself, but is there any library that can help me with it?

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest using Universal Tween Engine. You could add a short deleay and proper math equations to smooth out the camera transitions.

http://www.aurelienribon.com/blog/projects/universal-tween-engine/

Comment: yeap, Im using tweenEngine widely. I also was thinking about it. Thx!